# How to change to dynamic sql escape by using REPLACE function

Tags: oracle, plsql

so I try to change this code to dynamic SQL

```
SELECT  LISTAGG(accounting_dept || '-'||REPLACE(full_desc,'''',''''''), '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY accounting_dept)  FROM table
```

excute

```
12121-President''S Office
```

I changed to dynamic sql

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    ' SELECT  LISTAGG(accounting_dept || ''-''||REPLACE(full_desc,'''''',''''''''), ''; '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY accounting_dept)  FROM table '

INTO v_task;
```

the error is  ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

The problem is this part REPLACE(full_desc,'''''',''''''''),

how can I change to dynamic sql without the cauing error?

Comment: I don't see why you need REPLACE at all?  Why not just `SELECT  LISTAGG(accounting_dept || '-'||full_desc, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY accounting_dept)  FROM table1`?

Comment: "I changed to dynamic sql" - how? Is all of that now part of a statement in a string? If so what about the other single quotes you're using?

Comment: @AlexPoole sorry I made a mistake I fixed it, do you know the solution?

Comment: @TonyAndrews  I am really sorry I made a mistake, I should have explained more, if you know the solution, it would help me a lot so please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql here? Your example doesn't appear to need dynamic sql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put your statement into a variable you can output it before it's executed:

```
set serveroutput on

declare
  v_stmt varchar2(2000);
  v_task varchar2(2000);
begin
  v_stmt := 'SELECT  LISTAGG(accounting_dept || ''-''||REPLACE(full_desc,'''''',''''''''), ''; '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY accounting_dept)  FROM some_table';
  dbms_output.put_line(v_stmt );
  execute immediate v_stmt into v_task;
end;
/
```

which displays the statement it tries to execute, and then the error that gets:

```
SELECT  LISTAGG(accounting_dept || '-'||REPLACE(full_desc,''',''''), '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY accounting_dept)  FROM some_table

Error report -
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at line 7
```

If you run that generated statement manually in SQL Developer you'll get ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis; not entirely sure how or why you're getting that error dynamically too - it should be complaining about the semicolon first, with the ORA-00911.

You can see that the generates statement does not match the original static statement you started with. You need to have even more escaped quotes:

```
declare
  v_stmt varchar2(2000);
  v_task varchar2(2000);
begin
  v_stmt := 'SELECT  LISTAGG(accounting_dept || ''-''||REPLACE(full_desc,'''''''',''''''''''''), ''; '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY accounting_dept)  FROM some_table';
  dbms_output.put_line(v_stmt );
  execute immediate v_stmt into v_task;
end;
/

SELECT  LISTAGG(accounting_dept || '-'||REPLACE(full_desc,'''',''''''), '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY accounting_dept)  FROM some_table

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

But do as Tony Andrews suggests, and use the alternative quoting mechanism instead.

Not that you even need dynamic SQL here; this does the same:

```
declare
  v_task varchar2(2000);
begin
  SELECT LISTAGG(accounting_dept || '-'||REPLACE(full_desc,'''',''''''), '; ')
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY accounting_dept)
  INTO v_task
  FROM tableinto v_task;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am sorry I could not post whole procedure, but your explanation helped me a lot. I really appreciate your kind help and suggestion. Thanks to you, I learned a lot today. @alexpoole

Answer (score 4):

If turning the whole `select` into a string, use Q quote like this:

```
q'[SELECT  LISTAGG(accounting_dept || '-'||REPLACE(full_desc,'''',''''''), '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY accounting_dept)  FROM table]'
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! This helped me a lot!!!!!! I really appreciate your help.